# Add logging to a domain object at runtime

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Using the Grails Debug Console, is it possible to extend a class at runtime? I'm running into an issue with a domain object class and would like to add logging to the `beforeInsert()` method without restarting the application.

Comment: Why not just use a debugger and break before your insert call?

Comment: @JacobPersi, the application is already deployed. To use a debugger I would need to rerun the application in debug mode.